# Vue.js instant search from API REST Framework using axios

Tags: django, vue.js, search, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a problem. I want to create instant search, without any search button, that when i'm typing e.g. more than 3 letters, my results will be instant show below.

My code:

```
<template>
<div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">
    <div class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">
        <input v-model="keyword" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <div v-bind:key="result.id" v-for="result in results">
        <p>Results are: {{ result.title }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
  },
  data() {
      return {
          keyword: '',
          results: [],
      }
      },
  methods: {
      getResults() {
          axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/?search="+this.keyword)
          .then(res => (this.results = res.data))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
      },
      created() {
      this.getResults()
      }
}
</script>
```

Now my 'keyword' parameter is probably not passed to the url, because when I refresh the page, all records from APi are the results.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either call method when input changes

```
<input v-model="keyword" @input="getResults">
```

and method:

```
getResults() {
   if (this.keyword.length > 3)
     axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/?search="+this.keyword)
       .then(res => (this.results = res.data))
       .catch(err => console.log(err));
   }
}
```

Or watcher can be used. When keyword changes watcher will call getResults method.

```
watch: {
  keyword: "getResults"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use watcher for the `keyword` value update.
Whenever `keyword` is more than 3 letters, request the getResults() method to search.

```js
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
  },
  data() {
      return {
          keyword: '',
          results: [],
      }
  },
  watch: {
    keyword: function(newVal) {
      if (newVal.length >2) {
        this.getResults();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
      getResults() {
          axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/?search="+this.keyword)
          .then(res => (this.results = res.data))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
      },
      created() {
      this.getResults()
      }
}
```